Quarkus with Hibernate + panache throws a NoSuchFieldError when using Kotlin
I'm trying to learn kotlin, and to do so i'm turning a Quarkus (3.9.4) project I wrote in Java into a Kotlin one.
On the java side, everything works fine.
However, as soon as I try to run the kotlin version, I get this error.
12:02:30 ERROR [io.qu.ru.bo.StartupActionImpl] Error running Quarkus: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:113)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
    at com.petpals.bootstrap.Pals.main(Pals.kt:10)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION

The error seem to occure at this point when Hibernate is resolving configurations to merge them :

The BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION enum value can't seem to be picked for whatever reason, throwing the exception.
Here is the pom.xml content
 <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.12.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.9.23</kotlin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.9.4</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.2.5</surefire-plugin.version>
        <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>
        <sonar.projectKey>From-pets-to-pals_petpals-pals</sonar.projectKey>
        <sonar.organization>from-pets-to-pals</sonar.organization>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.petpals</groupId>
            <artifactId>petpals-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-qute</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-extensions</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jacoco</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>petpals-pals</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0.3922</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <exclClassLoaders>*QuarkusClassLoader</exclClassLoaders>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</destFile>
                            <append>true</append>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <javaParameters>true</javaParameters>
                    <jvmTarget>17</jvmTarget>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>all-open</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <pluginOptions>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=jakarta.ws.rs.Path</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=jakarta.persistence.Entity</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.PersistenceUnitExtension</option>
                    </pluginOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

I'm also using a PersistenceUnitExtension to setup my agroal data source programaticaly since my app functions with a keyvault from Azure to store some secrets.
Any help or clue is more than welcome. I tried downgrading the quarkus version hoping I could find a working hibernate-kotlin jar, to comment every bit of code not linked to JPA, without much success.
Thanks for your help

Please file an issue, this looks like a bug.

for completeness: Issues can be filed  here (github.com).

Issue created !
